# How to write to Tkinter element from another Python script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, multiple-instances

Let's say I have seperated my GUI and modules like this: gui.py, `module1.py`, `module2.py`, etc..

If I would like to initialize `module1.py`, I would click a button in `gui.py`, and it will start the `main()` function of `module1.py` sequentially (`module1.py` is imported to `gui.py`).

The problem is, I would like to be returned some data to `gui.py`, specifically some print-like strings that I would use on a textbox in the GUI. After some researching I found out that if I import `gui.py` back to `module1.py`, it would be a circular import which Python does not tolerate.

How should I approach this issue, what are really my options?

This is some code for sampling:

**module1.py**

```
import gui

... CODE ...

textvar = "GO TO GUI ASAP"
gui.App.write_to_gui(gui.App, textvar)

... CODE ...
```

**gui.py**

```
import module1
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter

...CODE...

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
       self.frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="transparent")
       self.frame_1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    def open_console_frame_1(self):
        self.console_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.frame_1, width=600,  height=400)
        self.console_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=10)
        self.console_textbox = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master=self.console_frame, font=("Calibri", 14),width=600,  height=400)
        self.console_textbox.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
    
    ...CODE...

    def write_to_gui(self, text):
    self.console_textbox.insert("end", text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The correct way is `gui.App.write_to_gui(textvar)` instead of `gui.App.write_to_gui(gui.App, textvar)`

Comment: Will not work like that, one variable not declared (self)

Comment: Move `write_to_gui()` inside `class App`. Not outside of `class App`

Comment: I'm very sorry.. The function should have been in the class from the beginning, edited how it should have been.

Comment: Exception:
App.write_to_gui() missing 1 required positional argument: 'textvariable',

Comment: Can you try this    gui.App.write_to_gui('*', textvar)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to answer your question.
One would be, that you should not "need" to call your main from the module. Instead return values from the module to your main app.

example:

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import module1


class App:
    WIDTH = 300
    HEIGHT = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.WIDTH}x{self.HEIGHT}')
        
        self._create_message_label()
        self.load_string_from_module_1()

    def load_string_from_module_1(self):
        current_string = self._get_string_from_module_1()
        self._set_message_string(current_string)

    def _create_message_label(self):
        self.message_string = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.message_string).pack()

    def _get_string_from_module_1(self) -> str:
        mod1 = module1.Module1()
        return mod1.get_a_string()

    def _set_message_string(self, new_string: str):
        self.message_string.set(new_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

**module1.py**

```
class Module1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_string = 'this is my string'

    def get_a_string(self) -> str:
        return self._my_string
```

The only relevant part for you question is when Module1 gets instantiated and then called with `mod1.get_a_string()`. This will return the needed string to the main app.

The other way around would be this example:

**main.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import module1


class App:
    WIDTH = 300
    HEIGHT = 100

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.WIDTH}x{self.HEIGHT}')
        self._create_message_label()
        mod1 = module1.Module1()
        mod1.do_some_things(self)

    def set_message_string(self, new_string: str):
        self.message_string.set(new_string)

    def _create_message_label(self):
        self.message_string = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.message_string).pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.root.mainloop()
```

**module1.py**

```
class Module1:
    def __init__(self):
        self._my_string = 'this is my string'

    def do_some_things(self, parent):
        parent.set_message_string(self._my_string)
```

Here the relevant part is `mod1.do_some_things(self)`, where `self` is the App class of main.py which is an argument for `set_message_string` in the Module1 class.

set_message_string does assign this to the variable parent which can be used to call methods of the main app.

I hope this makes sense to you.